# Mouseevent with overlaying SVG

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, mouseevent

I am wondering if its possible to have `mouseevents` on an `SVG` that is overlayed by another `SVG`.

```
<div id = "svgWrapper>
    <svg id = "overlayingSvg" width = "400" height = "400">
         <g>
             <circle>
             ....
    <svg id = "underlayingSvg" width = "400" height = "400">
         <g>
             <rect>
             ....
</div>
```

In this case, access the `underlayingSvg` with the mouse to register a `mouseevent` on the `rect` elements. The `circle` on the `overlayingSvg` need to have `mouseevents` too.

Comment: Couldn't you bind your events to the parent?

Comment: @Turnip Currently I am binding the events to my `svg` elements `circle` or `rect`.

Comment: considering the deleted answer below, you should clarify what you actually need. where you want events processed and where not.

Comment: @the8472 I realized. I clarified

Comment: then you might still be able to solve this with `pointer-events:none`as @Turnip suggested. It is an inheritable property, so you can set it on the parent element and restore the default on the circle.

Comment: @the8472 thats it. thanks!